# Get items from a list if an item contains two separate strings python

Tags: python, list, filter

I have the following list:

```
["west_sky_1_blue","west_sky_1_green","east_sky_blue","east_sky_green","west_sky_2_blue","west_sky_2_green"]
```

How can I get any item that contains string "west" and "blue" into a list?(So in this example, i want to get "west_sky_1_blue" and "west_sky_2_blue" into another list.

My original approach is something like this below but is not working

```
west_blue_list=[s for s in all_col if "west" && "blue"in s]
```

Comment: just replace `&&` by `and`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition is malformed, use `'west' in v and 'blue' in v`:

```
lst = ["west_sky_1_blue","west_sky_1_green","east_sky_blue","east_sky_green","west_sky_2_blue","west_sky_2_green"]

out = [v for v in lst if 'west' in v and 'blue' in v]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
['west_sky_1_blue', 'west_sky_2_blue']
```

Answer (score 1):

Your initial approach had the correct idea, but the wrong syntax.

```py
all_col = ["west_sky_1_blue","west_sky_1_green","east_sky_blue","east_sky_green","west_sky_2_blue","west_sky_2_green"]

west_blue_list = [s for s in all_col if "west" in s and "blue" in s]
```

**Alternatively, using `filter`:**

```py
west_blue_list = list(filter(lambda s: "west" in s and "blue" in s, all_col))
```

**Alternatively, using regular expressions and `filter`:**

```py
import re
pattern = re.compile("west.*blue")
west_blue_list = list(filter(pattern.search, all_col))
```

The previous one will only keep strings where `"west"` appears before `"blue"`; it wouldn't keep `"blue_sky_in_the_west"` if that was in the list.

**Alternatively, using `startswith` and `endswith`:**

```py
west_blue_list = [s for s in all_col if s.startswith('west') and s.endswith('blue')]
```

This one will only keep strings that start with 'west' and end with 'blue'; it wouldn't keep `"southwest_sky_blue"` if that was in the list.